# JavaScript - How can I test the equality of WeakSet?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to test if two (or more) WeakSets are equal?
So, I want this code to print out true

```js
var a = new WeakSet();
var b = new WeakSet();
a.add([3]);
b.add([3]);
console.log(isEqual(a, b)); // -> true
```

Comment: `[3] === [3]` is `false`, which is just the first problem here. The second being that you add these as literals, so there are no other references to the arrays, which makes them eligible for garbage collection. In a way `a` and `b` should therefore both be equal because they should both be empty but it might differ based on when GC runs.

Comment: Would like to know why you want to compare 2 WeakSet? or is that your requirement is to compare 2 arrays?

Comment: I'm trying to compare 2 WeakSets because I'm currently working on 'isEqual' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - you can't. `WeakSet`s [are not enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) so there is no way to test the equality of **values** in a `WeakSet`.

Currently your only option is to use `Array` here.
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript).

Also see [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods) if you want to use `Set` instead.

Though I doubt that your use case requires that kind of memory management, you may also consider [WeakReferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef) as part of your solution.

As a side note, `WeakSet`s have very few actual use-cases, so you probably should not settle for them.